# netstat -ln output on an ec2 instance (ubuntu ami)

Tags: 12.04

When I run netstat -l, my output is:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          :::*                    LISTEN
```

what does the foreign address section means here?

My expectation is for this server to listen from any host

Answer (score 0):

Foreign Address is the remote machine name or IP that is connected to 127.0.0.1:8080